# Android Room: How to know if a primary key exists?

Tags: android, android-room

With Android Room library, how do I write a Dao method that returns a boolean indicating whether a primary key exists in the database?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472103/sqlite-query-to-find-primary-keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite query to find primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472103/sqlite-query-to-find-primary-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite pragma contains this info(pk=1 on column if column is primary key) so executing a query on it joined with sqlite_master(to get all tables in db) should do it. my DAO syntax is a bit rusty but the query works

```
@Query("SELECT 
  count(*)!=0
FROM 
  sqlite_master AS m
JOIN 
  pragma_table_info(m.name) AS p
Where 
  p.pk=1")
 public abstract bool findPrimaryKeyExistsInDB();
```

https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragfunc

Comment: I was actually trying to find out if Room library has an API for it, but it looks like writing raw SQL is the only way so far.

Comment: room doesn't support pragma and i don't think it's on the roadmap since it's not a common usecase and if you need it rawquery/query handles it

Answer (score 0):

You can count and return (boolean) through following code:

```
@Query("SELECT count(*)!=0 FROM PERSON WHERE UID = :uid ")
boolean containsPrimaryKey(int uid);
```

where, uid -> your primary key 
PERSON-> your table name
It works me, hope work for you as well.